# ASGI_APPLICATION not working with Django Channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I followed the tutorial in the channels documentation but when I start the server `python3 manage.py runserver` it gives me this :

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 17, 2022 - 00:13:21
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

when I expected for it to give me this :

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 17, 2022 - 00:13:21
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.5 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'config.asgi.application'
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
})
```

It doesn't give any errors even when I change the `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'config.asgi.application` to `ASGI_APPLICATION = ''`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This could be due to the fact that the Django and channels versions you have used are not compatible
Try : `channels==3.0.4 and django==4.0.0`

Comment: Thanks, worked with Python 3.9.

Comment: (env4) PS D:\python project\learning django channels\channels> python --version
Python 3.9.0
(env4) PS D:\python project\learning django channels\channels> pip freeze      
asgiref==3.5.2
attrs==22.1.0
autobahn==22.7.1
Automat==22.10.0
cffi==1.15.1
channels==3.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==38.0.3
daphne==3.0.2
Django==4.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.4
incremental==22.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==22.1.0
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
Twisted==22.10.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.2

Comment: txaio==22.2.1
typing-extensions==4.4.0
tzdata==2022.6
zope.interface==5.5.1
(env4) PS D:\python project\learning django channels\channels>

Comment: For above version does not work for me.

Comment: According to the docs I added daphne at the top in the installed apps list. After that running the runserver command starts ASGI/Daphne server. Is it okay to do that?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! How did you find out about the compatibility of those versions? I couldn't find information on what channels version is compatible with what django version. Could you point me to a link or something? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think downgrading channels or Django just to support ASGI is a good idea thus I went for @reza_khalafi 's answer instead of downgrading Django.

Comment: 4.0.0 doesnt work at all but if you use 3.0.4 it works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

At the first:

```
pip install daphne
pip install channels
```

And then update setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Just this.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same with django=4.1.4, channels=4.0.0

My solution:

1. install channels with daphne (i did not remove or did anything to previously installed channels; operating in the same venv)

`python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]`

2. put daphne in INSTALLED APPS, do not put channels there:

`INSTALLED_APPS = ( "daphne", "django.contrib.auth",...`

3. in settings.py add ASGI_APPLICATION:

`ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.asgi.application"`

Comment: daphne not match

Comment: After running 'python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]' command getting an error 'no matches found: channels[daphne]'

Comment: @GulshanPrajapati perhaps you are using a console that interprets the brackets differently. Use `channels\["daphne"\]` instead

Answer (score 4):

From channels 4.0.0 Release Notes documentation:

> In order to allow users of other ASGI servers to use Channels without the overhead of Daphne and Twisted, the Daphne application server is now an optional dependency, installable either directly or with the daphne extra, as per the pip example above.
> Where Daphne is used daphne>=4.0.0 is required. The channels[daphne] extra assures this.

> **The runserver command is moved to the daphne package.**

> In order to use the runserver command, add daphne to your INSTALLED_APPS, before django.contrib.staticfiles:

> INSTALLED_APPS = [
> "daphne",
> ...
> ]

As you can see the runserver command is moved to the daphne package. So you have to install and include it as mentioned here before

Answer (score 0):

Use version of python that support by channels, you will found it at pypi channels page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found that there was a new release of Channels. Since the project's Pipfile did not specify a version, it was automatically upgraded.

Maybe you had the same issue, your question was asked 2 days after Channels v4.0 release.

Downgrading to v3.0.5 again solved the problem until I can properly upgrade.

Comment: Downgrading to V3.0.5 was the easiest solve for me as well.